# List child pages alphabetically

Tags: list

I am using the following code to list sub pages of a particular page.

How would I change ot to sort by alphabetical order?

```
<?php $args=array(
  'post_parent' => 15901,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'orderby' => 'the_title',
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <ul>
<?php
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li><h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php $brand_name  = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'brand_name', true); ?><?php echo $brand_name; ?>
            </a></h4>
        </li>
   <?php endwhile; } ?>
    </ul>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: It is in the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), `title`, not `the_title`

Comment: Or perhaps OP is trying to order by brand name.

Comment: wp_reset_query is for cleaning up after a `query_posts` call, you want to use `wp_reset_postdata` instead, and you need to call at the end of the if statement, not after it ( it cleans up after calls to `$my_query->the_post()` )

Comment: Also don't hardcode your post IDs, use `get_the_ID()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `'orderby' => 'the_title'` to `'orderby' => 'title'` then you will get the posts in alphabetical order.